# How do you write this in LaTeX?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

[image]

I currently need a way work with conjunctions and disjunctions in a similar way as with working with the notation for summations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I write

```
\begin{equation}
     \bigwedge_{i=1}^9 \bigwedge_{n=1}^9 \bigvee_{j=1}^9 p(i,j,n)
\end{equation}
```